# scrolling doesn't work even when using <ScrollView> (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, scrollview

I've tried every solution I could find on different sites, but couldn't find anything, hopefully someone here could help me.
There are no errors, just doesn't work to scroll.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="385dp"
    android:layout_height="540dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="gino.navigationface.bar_position"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_bar_position">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollIndicators="top|left|bottom|start|end|right">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="The Queen"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="#c0c0c0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text=""
                android:background="@drawable/the_queen"
                android:id="@+id/queenButton"
                android:onClick="theQueen"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Vasa Bar"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="#c0c0c0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/vasabar"
                android:background="@drawable/vasa_bar"
                android:onClick="vasaBar"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Italienska"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:textColor="#c0c0c0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:background="@drawable/italienska"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:textColor="#c0c0c0"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp">
                </TextView>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/källarn"
                android:background="@drawable/kallarn"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If needed I could post screenshots of the app

Comment: First use ScrollView as the parent and then LinearLayout as the child (exchange ScrollView with LinearLayout tags)

Comment: on which android version are you testing ?? and set layout width/height to match_parent

Comment: I'm using my phone, which is Lollipop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the **app_bar_bar_position.xml**, I placed the **android:background** in the  which made the scrolling not work

< android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="gino.navigationface.bar_position"
    **android:background="@drawable/background_blank">**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_bar_position" />
```

Comment: It didn't make any difference when I changed it, I still can't scroll...
I get that scroll bar on the side of the screen but even that only scrolls about 1mm (0,04 inches) and then stops.. Trying to scroll on the actual screen doesn't do anything

Comment: @GinoKalyun post the code after correction so that i may find any mistake

Comment: I changed the code you wrote with the one I changed

Comment: @GinoKalyun Glad to know that your problem is solved ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use this It will work

```
 <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:scrollIndicators="top|left|bottom|start|end|right"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="gino.navigationface.bar_position"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_bar_position">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
.................
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes the answer is simple. if we use scrollView just check once, in the emulator, instead of scrolling with mouse button, drag the screen down using mouse.
I had stuck there using mouse scroll button but actually in emulator it works with screen drag down by mouse.

Just check once:)

Answer (score 0):

Use **ScrollView** as the root view of layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/scroller"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout>
     ...
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If you use LinearLayout as root view, is won't scroll even you put an ScrollView inside LinearLayout.

Comment: I tried doing that and on the preview display in android studio makes the screen long enough to display everything, but when I start the app on my phone, it still won't scroll...

Comment: Can you post your modified layout file ?